# How to disabled / enable checkboxes on load with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to load the checkboxes enabled where the `.group` is checked. And disabled ones where `.group` is unchecked. I can switch them but cannot disabled the unchecked `.group` to disabled.

Upon loading, I expect all zones in `Group 2` clickable.
While all in `Group` 1 are grayed out but clickable later.

As well as when I uncheck the `Group` checkbox. All the zone must be disabled. They will only clickable when a `Group` is checked.

```js
$(function() {
  enable_cb();
  $(".group").click(enable_cb);
  $(".zone").attr("disabled",true);//disabled by default
});

function enable_cb() {
  $(this).closest('div').find(".zone").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="btn-group w-100" role="group">
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check group" id="g_1" name="g_1" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="g_1">Group 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check zone" id="zone_1a" name="zone_1a" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="zone_1a">Zone A</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check zone" id="zone_1b" name="zone_1b" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="zone_1b">Zone B</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check zone" id="zone_1c" name="zone_1c" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="zone_1c">Zone C</label>
      </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="btn-group w-100" role="group">
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check group" id="g_2" name="g_2" checked autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="g_2">Group 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check zone" id="zone_2a" name="zone_2a" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="zone_2a">Zone A</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check zone" id="zone_2b" name="zone_2b" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="zone_2b">Zone B</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check zone" id="zone_2c" name="zone_2c" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="zone_2c">Zone C</label>
      </div>
      </td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Please find the fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/b50gwmzu/

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the unchecked group checkboxes and disable their siblings and themselves

```js
  $("input.group").not(':checked').each(function(){
     $(this).siblings(':checkbox').addBack().prop('disabled', true);  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="btn-group w-100" role="group">
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check group" id="g_1" name="g_1" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="g_1">Group 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check zone" id="zone_1a" name="zone_1a" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="zone_1a">Zone A</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check zone" id="zone_1b" name="zone_1b" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="zone_1b">Zone B</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check zone" id="zone_1c" name="zone_1c" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="zone_1c">Zone C</label>
      </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="btn-group w-100" role="group">
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check group" id="g_2" name="g_2" checked autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="g_2">Group 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check zone" id="zone_2a" name="zone_2a" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="zone_2a">Zone A</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check zone" id="zone_2b" name="zone_2b" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="zone_2b">Zone B</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check zone" id="zone_2c" name="zone_2c" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="zone_2c">Zone C</label>
      </div>
      </td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: Why `Group 1` cannot click now?

Comment: Why ...because that's what you stated you wanted...all group 1 greyed out which to me means disabled. If that is not the expected behavior then the question needs to be a lot more specific

Comment: Sorry for my bad English causing the explain confuse. I mean `Group 1` greyed out because it's not checked. While `Group 2` is clickable because it's checked at onload.

Comment: And that's what I did. If it needs to be different then more explanation is needed

Comment: I appreciated your effort but I can't use it. I beg you a bit of time. Can you add `Group 1` clickable too?

Comment: Remove `addBack()` from my answer and it will not be disabled, only the siblings will be

Comment: I think this is what you are wanting https://jsfiddle.net/3o59wfLu/ The group checkboxes never get disabled but the others in each group do get disabled and enabled

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I'm looking for. Sorry for my bad explanation and wasting your time to fix over.

Comment: I ran into another problem. Should I ask here or create another question? That I want `Group 3 (a or b)` select to enable the siblings. https://jsfiddle.net/s04ecw5b/1/

Comment: Will be much cleaner if you can add a different class to the "other" in each collection. Then you can use `siblings('otherClassName')`

Comment: Hi, I got an issue on the last question. I want either `Group 3a` or `Group 3b` or both click. And enable the related class next to it. Could you please spend sometimes a look here : https://jsfiddle.net/njfykdtw/

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function toggleZones(zIndex) {
    var status = $("#g_" + zIndex).is(":checked");
    $("input[id^='zone_" + zIndex + "']").prop("disabled", !status);
  }

  $(".group").change(function() {
    toggleZones($(this).attr("id").slice(-1));
  });

  $(".group").each(function(i, el) {
    toggleZones($(el).attr("id").slice(-1));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="btn-group w-100" role="group">
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check group" id="g_1" name="g_1" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="g_1">Group 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check zone" id="zone_1a" name="zone_1a" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="zone_1a">Zone A</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check zone" id="zone_1b" name="zone_1b" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="zone_1b">Zone B</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check zone" id="zone_1c" name="zone_1c" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="zone_1c">Zone C</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="btn-group w-100" role="group">
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check group" id="g_2" name="g_2" checked autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="g_2">Group 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check zone" id="zone_2a" name="zone_2a" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="zone_2a">Zone A</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check zone" id="zone_2b" name="zone_2b" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="zone_2b">Zone B</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check zone" id="zone_2c" name="zone_2c" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="zone_2c">Zone C</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Clicking one of the Groups will Toggle if it is Enabled or Disabled.